# write after end error when uploading file using s3 aws sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, linode

I'm using s3 (aws sdk) for node.js to upload files/images into Linode Object Storage.
For really small files (less then 1 MB) is working ok, but when file is bigger then 1MB it throws the following error:

```
error Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:643:15)
at ClientRequest.end (_http_outgoing.js:763:7)
at features.constructor.writeBody ({pathtoproject}/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:137:14)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> ({pathtoproject}/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:102:14)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:605:11)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:507:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

This is my upload function:

```
const s3 = require('./index')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const uploadFile = (file, bucket) => {
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket, // pass your bucket name
    Key: `${uuidv4()}-${file.originalname}`, // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
    Body: file.buffer,
    ContentType: file.mimetype,
    ACL: 'public-read'
};
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.upload(params, (s3Err, data) => {
        if (s3Err) {
            reject(s3Err)
        } else {
            console.log(`Image uploaded at: ${data}`)
            resolve(data.Location)
        }
    });
 })
}  


module.exports = uploadFile
```

This is main config

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./aws/config.json');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({ httpOptions: { timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 }});

module.exports = s3
```

Comment: I can't spot any errors in this code, looks correct. can you share how you are calling the `uploadFile` method?

Comment: await uploadFile(img, 'main-images')
I'm using multer.single middleware  to get the file from the form body of the request

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Interesting part is that is working smooth for smaller files :( for this bigger then 1mb is throwing the error - but file will be saved to object storage also.

Comment: FYI promisified variants of the SDK functions have been available since 2016. No need to manually create promises around them. Just use `await s3.upload(params).promise()` or `return s3.upload(params).promise()` to return the promise to the caller to await.